is it mandatory to specify size of the vector when we using vector of vector?
vector<vector<int>>res(size);

I was working on some problem when I run the code with size its gave correct result but without size it throws seg-fault
vector<vector<int>> printGraph(int V, vector<pair<int,int>>edges) {
    vector<vector<int>>res;
    for (auto edge : edges) 
    {
        int u = edge.first;
        int v = edge.second;
        res[u].push_back(v);
        res[v].push_back(u);  
     }

     return res;
}

I need to now why its working only when I passed size

res[u] means accessing of the unth element of res... (so res is required to contain at least u elements for that access to be valid)

There is no difference between a vector and a vector that is an element of a vector. The difference is how you treat them in your code: you call push_back(v); for the inner vectors, but for the outer vectors you assume that elements are already present and call res[u]. Thats wrong

Change to res.at(u).push_back(v); to cause an exception to be thrown if u is out of bounds.

vector<vector<int>>res;  means that res.size() is zero (i.e. res contains no vector<int>s).   Referencing res[u] does not resize res to make u a valid index but (if res.size() is zero) causes undefined behaviour.  Same for res[v].    Your loop needs to ensure that res[u] and res[v] both exist, before calling their push_back() member function.    For example (assuming u and v are both non-negative) do res.resize(std::max(u, v) + 1); res[u].push_back(v); res[v].push_back(u);.

vector() creates an empty vector. Accessing the u or v index pf such a vector accesses memory that it doesn't own, and thus has potential to seg-fault.

it attempts to access memory it doesnt own. What it actually accesses is undefined
